# How to create a JSON object in which the value is not one of the primitive data types

Tags: java, json

How to send the following data as a json object in java:

```
{
    "name": "abc",
    "coordinates": [
        [
            [
                100,
                0
            ],
            [
                101,
                0
            ],
            [
                101,
                1
            ],
            [
                100,
                1
            ],
            [
                100,
                0
            ]
        ]
    ]
}
```

The question is since the value of coordinates is neither of the primitive data types how do I add it in the json object as a key value pair. Point to note: The value of coordinates is not a string

Comment: What JSON library are you using?

Comment: not sure, what you want mate, but that json you sent is VALID.

Comment: What key do you want, and what value? Your question isn't clear to me at the moment.

Comment: Please share a snippet of code showing how you would do that if value of coordinates would be a primitive type, like in {
    "name": "abc",
    "coordinates": 42} , you may also want to include list of your imports

Comment: Yes this json is valid. In selenium I want to creat a json object. I read the value of coordinate from an excel sheet but when I do so the value is read as a string

Comment: use `gson library`. it converts the object of a class into json object...

Comment: The libraries used by me are import org.json.JSONArray;
import org.json.JSONException;
import org.json.JSONObject;

Answer (score 3):

That structure is an object containing a property with a string value and another property with an *array* value. That array contains one entry, another array, which in turn has a series of entries, which are also arrays.

How you build that will depend on what JSON library you're using, but if you're using `javax.json`, you'd do *something* like this *(**see update below**)*:

```
JsonObject obj = Json.createObjectBuilder()       // The outer object
    .add("name", "abc")                           // `name`
    .add("coordinates", Json.createArrayBuilder() // `coordinates`
        .add(Json.createArrayBuilder()            // The one entry in `coordinates`
            .add(Json.createArrayBuilder()        // The various entries...
                .add(100)
                .add(0)
                .build()
            )
            .add(Json.createArrayBuilder()        // ...in the inner array
                .add(101)
                .add(0)
                .build()
            )
            // ...and so on
            .build()
        )
        .build()
    )
    .build();
```

And then if appropriate:

```
String json = obj.toString();
```

Now that you've said you're using `org.json`:

```
JSONObject obj = new JSONObject();       // The outer object
obj.put("name", "abc");                  // `name`
JSONArray coordinates = new JSONArray(); // `coordinates`
obj.put("coordinates", coordinates);
JSONArray innerArray = new JSONArray();  // The entry in `coordinates`
coordinates.put(innerArray);
JSONArray entry = new JSONArray();       // The various entries...
entry.put(100);
entry.put(0);
innerArray.put(entry);
entry = new JSONArray();                 // ...in the inner array
entry.put(101);
entry.put(0);
innerArray.put(entry);
// ...and so on.
```

And then if appropriate:

```
String json = obj.toString();
```